# The 'router' - how to make it right?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, routes, url-routing

I want to ask you for best solution for the router.

I have some tables in my database (articles, pages, categories etc.) which all has IDs.
I want to generate specific URL for each of them, eg. `/en/article/25-This-is-an-test-article`.

But how to get rid of that */article*, */page*, ... ? Users don't want to see it - it just increases the length of url ...

My first idea was simple router table:

```
CREATE TABLE `router` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But there is one fatal problem - It's impossible to set foreign key for the enitity_id column because it should refer to more columns and that is not possible in SQL.

My question is:
Do you think that I should stick with that solution (and ignore the foreign key )
or should I forgt about it and append the type in the URL ?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a mysql problem..  If you want a short url why not just use the id of the row as the identifier in the url to the article?

Comment: I don't see how this is a MySQL issue either - your web application can figure out the what article to return (what SQL statement to run) based on the URL request.

Comment: it's not pure mysql question, I just didn't know which tags and so I should use :D ... I'm looking for best approach in managing url's. I don't like that 'article', 'page' etc. identifiers in url - but I also don't know the best way how to get rid of them.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose for your question either.  But it seems like truncating the URL to everything after the last `/` might be what you are asking about.

Comment: ahh, is that really so hard ? I want `/en/article/55-something` to become `/en/55-something` - with the best performance, with the best and cleanest way (the problem is WHERE and HOW to save the info that 55-something IS an article, not the page)

Comment: In a column of the row with ID 55, which you found by the 55 being in the URL. Once you retrieve that row, you know whether to display a 'page' or 'article'.

Comment: Just a side note: If you're concerned about URL length (*and have the ability to*) you can store the language preference in a session variable; now you're down 3 (*or more*) characters.

Comment: Bracketworks yes, If you dont think about it in depth, then this is really best approach. But what about search engines ? Same url and x contents ? This isn't the best way really. And no, I don't care about the URL length but about it's readability - it just seems stupid to me to see 'article' in 'articles' url ... Dan Grossman yes, I know that this is possible, but I ask for the best and fastest solutions. Querying x table's to get the right one is not the best way I think ... that's why I tagged it with 'MySQL' - best solution will be in good SQL query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want `/en/article/55-something` to become `/en/55-something` - with
>   the best performance, with the best and cleanest way (the problem is
>   WHERE and HOW to save the info that 55-something IS an article, not
>   the page)

The best place for that information is right there in the URL, so that you don't have to muck about with flimsy, best-guess lookups.

Short answer: you're already doing it properly.

Comment: precisely what I was going to write.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I just wanted to make sure there is no better way ... all comments here makes me sad that I'm perfect :D thank you for help